# How to style text without tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to style text without tags with jQuery. 
The piece of code below finds text without tags:

```
$("body").each(function(i) {
var foundElement = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();

 });
```

Now I want to style the text using the function css() like this:

```
$("body").each(function(i) {
var foundElement = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
foundElement.css({'color':'green'});

});
```

In the console I get this error message:

**TypeError: foundElement.css is not a function**

Comment: `.text` returns a string, not a DOM element you can style.

Comment: You could just use `addClass()` at the end of your chain... Minus `.text()` (Naturally, define an associated class!)

Comment: Instead of using the clone/remove children method of getting the text you could use `filter()`, however this will still return you the textNodes and they cannot be styled with CSS so you have the same problem. The only way to do what you require is to wrap the text in an element and place the styling rules on that

Comment: What makes you believe that jQuery can style text without using tags?!!

Answer (score 0):

foundElement.style.color = 'green';

Although this is not ideal, you should use .addClass / removeClass and maintain the css separately.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I get this error: foundElement.style is undefined. If I use addClass the console says: addClass is not a function.

Comment: then you must not have a domElement in foundElement. Those are domElement properties and methods.